# Is there a convenient way to (re)create a table based on changes in source tables?

Tags: sql-server

I have to provide data from our inventory management software (using MS SQL Server 13 / 2016 as backend) in various views / reports; there are about 25 reports which are queried up to twice an hour.

All reports include data queried from multiple tables, including some calculations (based on those table values), so my idea was to store this core report table in the DB for shared use by the reports, so that I don't have to query and calculate data over and over while it has not changed.

In a pseudo 'function' , this would be:
`CoreTable = ComplexQueryFrom(MainT1, MainT2, MainT3, AuxT4, AuxT5, ...)`
where MainTx tables hold the important data, and AuxTx are only lookups etc.

My reports should query this CoreTable, but whenever one of the MainTables have changed since the last creation of my CoreTable, the CoreTable should get recreated with the complex query.

I've read / heard about

1. Triggers, but those would update every time the MainTables would change (source side), not only when changed AND needed (result)?
2. Change Data Capture, but I'm not even sure if that's the right way (besides being quite complex, way beyond a CTE or stored procedure)
3. Indexed views: Cannot be used because of subqueries, EXISTS, MAX and UNION - all of them are not allowed

Any ideas or even solutions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you investigated 'indexed views' : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/dd171921(v=sql.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN to see if they would accomplish what you want?

Comment: This is too vague and too broad for SO and will likely be closed. But this might be a big premature optimization effort that can (perhaps) easily be handled by the database engine. I suggest you write some sample report queries and test their impact on the system BEFORE you do anything else. BTW schema changes (triggers, CDC) are generally frowned upon for licensed sotware.

Comment: @E.J.Brennan: Thanks, forgot to mention the indexed views - I can't use them since the query for my CoreTable makes use of subqueries, EXISTS, MAX and UNION - all of them are not allowed in an indexed view.

Comment: @SMor - Thanks too! Well, maybe someone comes up with some clever trick. And as for testing the queries, they are already used in our current views (with the same core queries) - and the heavier ones take 40-50 seconds to run - each time, even if just a WHERE clause on the result set has changed. My tries with a manually created core table were << 1s

Comment: About indexed views - you may be able use combination of those. We for example use them for some kind of store management - final query includes unions and left joins (no indexing possible), but it is querying data from many indexed views. Does work well in our scenario, much better than updating tables in triggers (earlier solution).

Answer (score 0):

If your whole idea is ,not to tax core tables..I would go with Transactional replication..

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/transactional/transactional-replication?view=sql-server-ver15